# Suitable companion monitors for HP LP3065 30" primary monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have an HP LP3065 30" monitor - now I want to add a couple of companion screens to either side of it - I've heard to people suggesting 21" monitors in portrait mode - but it seems difficult to find a suitable panel these day, as 22" wide-screen monitors have become common, and I can't seem to find anything with a suitable 1600 pixel width.

Can anyone recommend a suitable monitor, and suggest what criteria are best for picking a suitable monitor - what's important to consider - I'm thinking things like:

- Exact resolution match?
- Viewing angle?
- Small/thin bezel?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a 20" 1600x1200 screen with this exact monitor, and the height is perfect. I have heard that this is the only resolution and size that will match up perfectly, though have not tried any other screens, such as 1600x900, etc.

The problem with doing this is that the dell 2007FP looks yellow in comparison, or the LP3065 looks blue in comparison to the dell. I am currently looking at the HP LP2065. Hopefully the colors will be closer.

on the other hand, it is possible that the dell i purchased was simply old or defective.

Comment: Two tips. 1) colour profiles on the monitors. 2) Colour profiles in windows (or other OS).